# Parse Push Notification Cloud Code Error?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

**UPDATE:** I was getting this error because of a bug that Parse-Server 2.2.17 has. I fixed it by going back to 2.2.16.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Here is my cloud code:

`Parse.Cloud.define("Messages", function(request, response) {

var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
    alert: "New Event Added",
    sound: "default"
    }
    },{
    success: function(){
        console.log("Push Sent!")
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    },
  useMasterKey: true
```

});
});`

Here is the error I am getting: [image]

And then this is how I am calling the code: `PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("Messages", withParameters: nil) { (object, error) in

```
            if error == nil {

                print("Success!")

            } else {

                print(error)
            }
        }
```

index.js: [image]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the following code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
// query condition (where equal to .. etc.)

var payload = {
    alert: "New Event Added",
    sound: "default" 
};





Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query
    data: payload
}, {
        success: function () {

        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
```

Please notice that i remove the **useMasterKey** if you want to add useMasterKey you need to insert it inside closures but for me it's works without the useMasterKey

the useMasterKeyVersion should look like the following:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query
    data: payload
},
{
   useMasterKey: true
},
{
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```

The promises version (according to best practices):

```
Parse.Push.send({where: query,data: payload})
.then(function(){
    // success
},function(error){
    // error .. 
});
```

**Update**

by looking at your index.js file it looks like you didn't add the facebook oauth to your 3-party authentication logins.
so you will need to add the following:

```
oauth: {
   facebook: {
     appIds: "FACEBOOK APP ID"
   }
}
```

below your **emailAdapter** config and inside "FACEBOOK APP ID" put the app ID that you created in facebook developers

Comment: That code didn't work for me either. I still get the same error in the logs as I posted in the question about "Cant set headers." Could you please tell me what version of parse you're using? If you have any settings in heroku that you had to have to make it work? I am using the most updated version of parse and I was using OneSignal Push Adapter as well in my index.js file. But I was getting that error way before I used the push adapter.

Comment: I am using the latest version of parse 2.2.17. Can you please try to call to response.success() in the success block and response.error() in the error block and see if the callback is being called?

Comment: Okay, I am using that version as well. Do you have any other suggestions on maybe what the problem is? Or what I can do to fix it? Before I updated Parse, I was getting an error on my .p12 file saying it was unrecognized. Even though it was there. Then I updated parse on my terminal, and that error went away. But now ever since I have been getting the error about not being able to set headers after their sent.

Comment: I just used your method to implement the "response" methods in the code blocks, and still got the same error. I feel like I literally have tried everything, and nothing has worked lol. Ive been stuck on this 1 error for 3 days.

Comment: When I send pushes from the OneSignal dashboard, they go to my phone. Its just when I try and call the cloud code from my app is when I have the problem. I could also have sent pushes from my Parse dashboard as well when I was using Parse for the Push Notifications. But again, it didn't work from the Cloud Code.

Comment: I have found out it is a Node.js error. I cant use my cloud code for anything. Even if I only do "Console.log("This is a test")" , it still throws the same error.

Comment: Can you please paste your index.js file (i want to see how you configure the cloud code file)

Comment: I just added the file as a picture.

Comment: ok, i edit my answer. You should add facebook to your 3-party login providers.. look at the answer for further instructions..

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Is this just an implementation I should do. Or will this possibly fix my issue?

Comment: Okay, I just implemented the oauth function. Still got the same error though. Not sure if that was supposed to solve it or not. But thank you for recommending that. I also appreciate all of your help so far too.

Comment: Do you know how to roll back Parse Server Versions? The error is caused by a 2.2.17 bug. So I need 2.2.16. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: try npm install parse-server@2.2.16

Comment: It didn't work. After it was done downloading. it said "parse-server@2.2.16 - INVALID"

Comment: for me it worked.. you need to run this command inside the folder where you install parse-server. If you want to modify the deployed version then you need to change the package.json file to point to 2.2.16

Comment: I got it working earlier today, thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

in main.js put this code

```
// SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION
Parse.Cloud.define("push", function(request, response) {

  var user = request.user;
  var params = request.params;
  var someKey = params.someKey
  var data = params.data

  var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
  recipientUser.id = someKey;

  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("userID", someKey);


  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
    data: data
  }, { success: function() {
      console.log("#### PUSH OK");
  }, error: function(error) {
      console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
  }, useMasterKey: true});

  response.success('success');
});



// SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION FOR ANDROID
Parse.Cloud.define("pushAndroid", function(request, response) {

  var user = request.user;
  var params = request.params;
  var someKey = params.someKey
  var data = params.data

  var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
  recipientUser.id = someKey;

  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("userID", someKey);


  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
    data: {
       alert: data
    }
}, { success: function() {
      console.log("#### PUSH OK");
  }, error: function(error) {
      console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
  }, useMasterKey: true});

  response.success('success');
});
```

in xcode project do like that to send push notification

```
     // Send Push notification
        let pushStr = "@\(PFUser.current()![USER_USERNAME]!) | \n\(self.lastMessageStr)"


        let data = [ "badge" : "Increment",
                     "alert" : pushStr,
                     "sound" : "bingbong.aiff",

            ] as [String : Any]
        let request = [
            "someKey" : self.userObj.objectId!,
            "data" : data

            ] as [String : Any]
        PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "push", withParameters: request as [String : Any], block: { (results, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print ("\nPUSH SENT TO: \(self.userObj[USER_USERNAME]!)\nMESSAGE: \(pushStr)\n")
            } else {
                print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
```

Comment: Please explain some of the code you have written. You help is appreciated, but if OP knows details about your code, it would make more sense